# Sorting by second column in pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort the values of my pandas series by the second 'column' in my series.

This is code I have:

```
merged_clean.groupby('weeknum')['time_hour'].value_counts()
```

This is a sample of the data I am trying to sort:

```
weeknum   time_hour
16-22Jun  10.0         50
          11.0         50
          15.0         44
          12.0         41
          14.0         38
          13.0         34
          16.0         33
          8.0          30
          9.0          29
          18.0         28
          20.0         28
          21.0         23
          19.0         20
          17.0         19
          22.0         16
          7.0          12
          23.0          8
          0.0           5
          6.0           5
          3.0           4
          1.0           3
          2.0           3
          4.0           2
          5.0           2
2-8Jun    11.0         66
          12.0         56
          9.0          55
          13.0         53
          10.0         52
          14.0         41
```

The idea is to sort this such that it is sorted by time_hour. I know I have tried this

```
merged_clean.groupby('weeknum')['time_hour'].value_counts().sort_values()
```

but from what I see, this sorts the rows by the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) by second level specified by name or number:

```
merged_clean.groupby('weeknum')['time_hour'].value_counts().sort_index(level=['time_hour'])
```

Or:

```
merged_clean.groupby('weeknum')['time_hour'].value_counts().sort_index(level=1)
```

But if need sort both levels in `MultiIindex`:

```
merged_clean.groupby('weeknum')['time_hour'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

the explanation is here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

```
merged_clean.groupby('weeknum')['time_hour'].value_counts().sort_values().sort_index(level=1)
```

Comment: This gives me this error message TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'by'
 Note: its a pandas series not a dataframe

Comment: Still getting an error message: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @Emm sorry. I forgor about sorting index